# Spring Boot : perform a @query using a foreing key

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get a bean using a foreing key as follow :

-- the 1st bean containing the foreign Key (user_id : id) :

```html
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class Class_1{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
       //code
            )
    @GeneratedValue(    
       //code
            )
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

   /**
   * constructors , getters and setters, ... */
  }
```

-- The 2nd bean i want to fill using the foreign Key :

```html
@Entity
@Table
public class User{
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            // code
            )
    @GeneratedValue(    
            //code
            )
    private Long id;

   /**
   * attributes, constructors , getters and setters, ... */
}
```

here are my Tables :

```html
Table Class_1
+ ID + USER_ID +
+----+---------+
+ 1  +   1     +

Table User
+ ID + PARAM_1 + PARAM_2 + ... + PARAM_N +
+----+---------+---------+-----+---------+
+ 1  +  value_1+ value_2 + ... + value_n +
```

Now this is the Query i try to execute :

```html
    @Query("SELECT * FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user_id.id=?1")
    public List<Class_1> findClass_1ByUser(Long userId);
```

or (but still doesnt work :

```html
@Query("SELECT * FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user_id=?1")
    public List<Class_1> findClass_1ByUser(Long userId);
  
  @Query("SELECT * FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user=?1")
    public List<Class_1> findClass_1ByUser(User user);
```

The exception :
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List package.class_1.Class_1Repository.findClass_1ByUSer(java.lang.Long)!

any help ?

Thank you in advence :)

Comment: SELECT `c` FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user_id=?1

Comment: yes i just found out that removing "SELECT * " was working fine .. .for a reason i dont understand. But thank you Sergeant Cortez :) 

@Query("FROM Class_1 c WHERE c.user.id=?1") => work

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared a [HQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) query you may either replace the `*` with the object alias `SELECT c FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user_id=?1` or remove the `SELECT` e.g `FROM CLass_1 c WHERE c.user_id=?1`